# Get data using group by clause by removing/trimming spaces

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a column like this:

```
Occupations
------------
Housewife
House wife
Housework
House work
```

I want data using group by;

Here "Housewife" and "House wife" are similar data only difference is space between two words; Because it makes different data if we use the group by which is wrong

I want my table column like

```
Occupations
------------
Housewife
Housework
```

Can we remove redundancy from column using group by.....or any other way to get data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`translate()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html) to eliminate spaces from a string, e.g.

```
with the_data(occupation, amount) as (
    values
        ('Housewife', 1),
        ('House wife', 2),
        ('Housework', 3),
        ('House work', 4)
    )

select 
    translate(occupation, ' ', '') as occupation,
    sum(amount) as amount
from the_data
group by 1;

 occupation | amount 
------------+--------
 Housewife  |      3
 Housework  |      7
(2 rows)
```